# iPhone 6 plus block landscape orientation

Tags: uiinterfaceorientation, iphone-6-plus

I'm developing an iOS application which runs on iPhone and iPad. For iPhone it takes only portrait orientation, for iPad only landscape. In info file all types of orientation are turned on. The correct orientation calculates in base view controller method `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

It works perfectly for iOS 7 and 8 on all kind of devices except iPhone6+.

When I manually put the device to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight` (before running my app) I see that the system rotates other application icons on home screen like iPad does. After that I run my application and it identifies that the orientation is `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` although the real device orientation is landscape.

As I understand it's a new feature supported only by iPhone6+. But I want to avoid this behaviour and show my UI in portrait mode on this device.

Does anybody know how to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and everywhere in App I had allowed only portrait orientation. Turns out, in ..info.plist I had an entry:  "Supported interface orientations" and it had all four orientation types. I removed all but portrait and now - even if iPhone 6 Plus is in landscape (on homescreen) and I re-open my application, it forces iPhone 6 Plus to rotate back to portrait.